# Histogram Using 1st Row as Labels and Columns as Bins

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I am trying to make a histogram plot that uses the first row as the xlabels and that counts the entries in each column, starting from the 3rd entry down, for each distinct bin (total entries in 1st column dictates the size of the 1st bin, and so on). After doing some digging online and trying a few methods, I have not been able to come up with code that produces anywhere near what I need, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like something that could quite easily be pre-processed using another tool then plotted in gnuplot. Would this be a possibility? What platform are you using?

Comment: @TomFenech I'm open to trying that - what would you recommend? I'm using Linux Mint 16 Petra

Comment: I was thinking of one of the standard tools, maybe AWK or something like that. Could you edit your question and add some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the text in the first row of your file directly into gnuplot by using a bash command within backquotes. Imagine you have the following file:

```
cat >file<<eof
text1 text2
text3 text4
eof
```

Then, in gnuplot, you can import, say `text1` to variable `a` and `text4` to variable `b` using awk:

```
a="`awk 'FNR==1 {print $1}' file`"
b="`awk 'FNR==2 {print $2}' file`"
```

Now you can use them as you wish, for instance `set xlabel a` will print `text1` as the xlabel.